# comparing 2 population proportions

Tags: t-test, maximum-likelihood, proportion, z-test

What are the methods to compare proportions from 2 independent populations

i know we can use the z-test or t test for comparing 2 proportions

what about Miettinens & Nurimens Liklihood Score test, Farmington & Mannings Liklihood score test, etc. Ive heard of them but not been able to understand them completely and most books dont even mention them, what is the difference between these tests and the usual z test.